# Render page under new URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to render a new HTML page under the index url.
For example render wb.html with ('/') url. Is there a way to do this?

OR an alternative would be to add html to an .html file when user = logged in and they came from the login page. Here is what I have (doesn't work)

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        #login
        user = form.get_user()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request, 'posts/wb.html', 'form':form) #Of course this doesn't render
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
context = {
    'form' : form
}
return render(request, 'posts/login.html', context)
```

Comment: what do you mean "new" ? to specify what pages are rendered at which url just look up urls.py. The first page of the django tutorial explains this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I do know the structuring. By new I mean a new one I have made. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have rendered a `.html` on your `/` page. Now lets create two file named (i guess) `public-home.html` and `private-home.html`.

Then, I hope you have view for `/` like following,

```
def index(request):
    _context = {
        'authenticated': request.user.is_authenticated
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', _context)
```

*Now check on `index.html`*

```
<div>
    {% if authenticated %}
       {% include "private-home.html" %}
    {% else %}
       {% include "public-home.html" %}
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

Comment: for my regular / i have an index.html for it. The entire purpose for this is to show a red banner at the top of the index page that says "welcome back, {{user.get_username}}" when they login, but not for people who haven't. Maybe there is a way you can help me with that?

Comment: Learn Django and it's templating first.

Comment: Templating was the answer after all! Awfully helpful thanks!